# XML to JSON in python

Tags: python, xml, converters, elixir-jason

I have been trying to convert a dataset file in `xml` format to `json`. I tried many solutions, non worked. I always got the same error:

> ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 67667, column 103

I tried `untangle`, `xmltodict`,  `pandas_read_xml`

This is my code for my attempt with `pandas_read_xml`:

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
df = pdx.read_xml("Ryiadh_utf_8.xml")
```

Comment: better use some xml library to parse, then to json. `lmxl` is an option.

Comment: Jason or JSON??

Comment: Yor xml is invalid - fix it

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in your input, check the error message: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html#xml.parsers.expat.errors.messages

Comment: @luk2302 sorry it's JSON

Comment: @balderman How ?

Comment: @ahad Navigate to line 67667, column 103 and see what is wrong there.